# How to do an advanced multiplication with panda dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have a dataframe1 of 1802 rows and 29 columns (in code as df) - each row is a person and each column is a number representing their answer to 29 different questions.

I have another dataframe2 of 29 different coefficients (in code as seg_1).

Each column needs to be multiplied by the corresponding coefficient and this needs to be repeated for each participant.

For example - 1802 iterations of q1 * coeff1, 1802 iterations of q2 * coeff2 etc
So I should end up with 1802 * 29 = 52,258

but the answer doesn't seem to be this length and also the answers aren't what I expect - I think the loop is multiplying q1-29 by coeff1, then repeating this for coeff2 but that's not what I need.

```
questions = range(0, 28)
co = range(0, 28)

segment_1 = []
for a in questions:
    for b in co:
        answer = df.iloc[:,a] * seg_1[b]
        segment_1.append([answer])
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper encoding of the coefficients as a Pandas frame makes this a one-liner

```
df_person['Answer'] = (df_person * df_coeffs.values).sum(1)
```

and circumvents slow `for`-loops. In addition, you don't need to remember the number of rows in the given table `1802` and can use the code without changes even if you data grows larger.

For a minimum viable example, see:

```
# answer frame
df_person = pd.DataFrame({'Question_1': [10, 20, 15], 'Question_2' : [4, 4, 2], 'Question_3' : [2, -2, 1]})

# coefficient frame
seg_1 = [2, 4, -1]
N      = len(df_person)
df_coeffs = pd.DataFrame({'C_1': [seg_1[0]] * N, 'C_2' : [seg_1[1]] * N, 'C_3' : [seg_1[2]] * N})

# elementwise multiplication & row-wise summation
df_person['Answer'] = (df_person * df_coeffs.values).sum(1)
```

giving

[image]

for the coefficient table `df_coeffs`

[image]

and answer table `df_person`

[image]

Comment: The data has been imported from excel so I don't think I have the formatting wrong, is that what you mean? Also - I need to multiply df_person[: , 0] * df_coeffs[0,0] then repeat for  df_person[: , 1] * df_coeffs[0,1] and so on, for 1802 participants repeated for 29 different questions

Comment: You didn't provide an example of `df` or `seg_1` which keeps us guessing. We cannot recreate the error. This made me create a minimum reproducible example. With a little tweaking, you'll be able to format your two data frames to fit the code above.